# Umbraco - Only Get Child Elements of an Document Type

Tags: umbraco, traversal, children

I have a structure link below

PageOne

- Columns

  --     ColumnItem-One

  --     ColumnItems-Two

  --     ColumnItems-Three

  --     ColumnItems-Four

PageTwo

- Columns

  --     ColumnItems-OneB

  --     ColumnItems-TwoB

I have a partial view which I want to display each of the children Column items but at the moment I am using descendants which is returning all 6 items instead of 4 on PageOne and 2 on PageTwo.

My code is

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var root = Model.Content;
    var tiles = root.Descendants("tiles");



    if(tiles.Count() > 0)
    {
        <div class="row tile-row">
            @foreach(var node in tiles)
            {
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <h3>@(node.GetPropertyValue("tileTitle"))</h3>
                        @(node.GetPropertyValue("tileBodyText"))<br/>
                        <a class="btn btn-more" href="@(node.GetPropertyValue("tileButtonLink"))">@(node.GetPropertyValue("tileButtonText"))</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            }
        </div><!--/.row-->
    }
}
```

If I change descendants to Children() i get an error page.

Thansk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call the partial view from your `PageOne` or from your `PageTwo`, then you can do the following if you are using the strongly typed object:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    // Get this PageOne or PageTwo object
    var page = Model.Content;

    // Get the column node that is descendant of this page
    var column = root.Descendants("columnAlias");

    // Get all children of the column node that are published
    var childs = column.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible());

    if(childs.Count() > 0)
    {
        <div class="row tile-row">
            @foreach(var node in childs)
            {
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <h3>@(node.GetPropertyValue("tileTitle"))</h3>
                        @(node.GetPropertyValue("tileBodyText"))<br/>
                        <a class="btn btn-more" href="@(node.GetPropertyValue("tileButtonLink"))">@(node.GetPropertyValue("tileButtonText"))</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            }
        </div><!--/.row-->
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this mivaweb i ended up achieving this using -                       var columns = CurrentPage.FirstChild("columns").Children("columnItem").Where("Visible");